# NFC iOS: NFC Tag Reading with out notification

Tags: ios, ios13, core-nfc

When I read NFC tag when app is in background, a notification appears. I have written URL scheme data `myurl://...` onto NFC tag. So, when I tap on the notification my app opens and take necessary actions as per payload.

But, when my app is in the foreground, still notification appears. And, I have to tap on the notification so that an action can be taken on the app.

Can I just directly read the NFC tag with out default NFC Read panel and notification?

[image]

Comment: On iOS 13.1 it is possible to disable user confirmation when using a personal automation based on a NFC tag within the shortcuts app. I don't know if this will/is possible when using your own app.

Comment: The notification itself can be hidden by disabling notifications for the Shortcuts app in the iOS settings. But this does not help, because nothing would be executed :)

Comment: @Klaas: I came across that too. But if I have to release an app, then it would be difficult to release shortcut or user has to install shortcut. And the shortcut cannot send information to my app, or can it?

Comment: You can use Siri intents to make your app "scriptable". Then let your user manually define a simple NFC -> your intent shortcut. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/resolving_and_handling_intents or https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/213/

Comment: @Klaas: Problem with that is... shortcuts also is showing notification. :) And, iOS system also is showing notification.

Comment: In case of NFC triggered personal automations you can at least disable the need for manually confirming the shortcut.

Comment: Anything on that @Chandra?

Comment: @raed: No raed. We moved on with notification pattern. User Study failed. Users did not give good feedback that they have to tap on the notification always that is not easily in the reach. We stopped the product after the pilot.

Comment: @Chandra sorry to hear that! And really appreciate your feedback.